# awesome wm - Can't set screen resolution

Tags: linux-mint, awesome-wm

I use **awesome wm** and use **xrandr** to set screen resolution.

But I accidently pressed **mod4+p** (win+p) and since then I can't set my screen resolution correctly.

I have a laptop and a VGA screen of 1920*1080, but now the second one is always a copy of the laptop screen. In xfce4 I don't have this problem.

(mint 14 32bit + awesome wm)

thanks!

Comment: Try to press it one more time (Win+P)

Comment: @Alex It just turns off my VGA screen now.